# Doing vector manipulations on Mathematica

Tags: programming, vector, vector-calculus, physics, tensors

This is hopefully a simpler version of this previous unanswered [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23496/solving-recursion-relations-using-mathematica) of mine.

Let me just focus on the two expressions $F_2^{(s)}$ and $F_3^{(s)}$ given in A.3 and A.4 of page 19 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.7182v2.pdf).

- How do I get Mathematica to just even manipulate such vector expressions? Like if I want to calculate $(F_2^{(s)})^2$ or $F_2^{(s)} F_3^{(s)}$ etc?

---

To make the question clear let me add in some more details about what I exactly want,

I define the function F2s as,

```
F2s[q_, k1_] := (5/
14) + (3 (Norm[k1])^2)/(28 (Norm[q])^2) + (3 Norm[
   k1]^2)/(28 (Norm[q - k1])^2) - (5)/(28 (Norm[q])^2 (Norm[
    q - k1])^(-2)) - (5)/(28 (Norm[q])^(-2) (Norm[
    q - k1])^(2)) + ( (Norm[
   k1])^4)/(14 (Norm[q])^2 (Norm[q - k1])^2 )
```

But when I ask it to be squared all I get is this! 
(basically nothing has been done and the situation doesn't change with taking a FullSimplify either)

```
(2 Norm[k1]^4 - 5 (Norm[q]^2 - Norm[-k1 + q]^2)^2 + 3 Norm[k1]^2 (Norm[q]^2 + Norm[-k1 + q]^2))^2/(784 Norm[q]^4 Norm[-k1 + q]^4)
```

I would have wanted the answer to be given in the way I gave the functions $F2s$ - as a sum of fractions each of which is a product of powers of $q$, $k1$ and $\vert \vec{q} - \vec{k1}\vert$. How do I get that?

Comment: Those aren't vectors at all. The contain vectors, but they're scalars. What do you mean by "manipulate"? Surely not `Manipulate`, but what *exactly*?

Comment: @Jens Like, could tell me how I can get Mathematica to calculate say $(F_2^{(s)}(\vec{k},\vec{k}-\vec{q}))^2$ ? .. for example..or if you could help solve the previous question linked from here..

Comment: How about if you tell us what $F_2^(s)$ is, and we'll tell you how to calculate $F_2^(s) (k,k-q)$ where k and q are vectors.

Comment: @bills Didn't get you. $F_2^{(s)}$ function is as defined in equation A.3 on page 19 of my linked paper. I want to be able to say take the square of it. How do I do it?

Comment: @bills I have added more details into the question. I guess now the question is more clear about what I want.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `Expand` instead of `FullSimplify` ?

Comment: @SimonWoods That does seem to help but it still doesn't seem to "understand" what a vector is. Like if I now evaluate F2s[p1,-k2] then it gives the answer in terms of stuff like Norm[-k2] - it doesn't understand that Norm[-k2] = Norm[k2]. Also once I have defined what what the function F2s is I want to be to able to evaluate the function on any combination of vectors like say F2s[k2+p1,k2+k1] wher k2, k1 and p1 are all vectors - how can this be done? I want it to behave like a function which takes two vectors and gives me its square/cube etc in the form I explained

Comment: @SimonWoods You can see this example - like if you put in, (F2s[q, k1]*F2s[-q, k2]  *F2s[k2 + q, k2 + k1])*(Norm[-q]^n*
     Norm[-k1 + q]^n*Norm[-k2 - q]^n) // Expand // TraditionalForm  then one can see that in various terms Norm[-q] and Norm[q] haven't been combined - hoping that everything else has worked out right!

Comment: I had to put in Norm[-k2-q] and Norm[-q] intentionally to cause at least some simplification! Otherwise even those would have been messed!

Answer (score 5):

Based on the assumption that those F functions produce scalar results…

If you just want to manipulate the vectors as entities without considering their components, then you can enter the function for F2s

```
f2s[q_, k1_] := (5/
14) + (3 (Norm[k1])^2)/(28 (Norm[q])^2) + (3 Norm[
   k1]^2)/(28 (Norm[q - k1])^2) - (5)/(28 (Norm[q])^2 (Norm[
    q - k1])^(-2)) - (5)/(28 (Norm[q])^(-2) (Norm[
    q - k1])^(2)) + ((Norm[
   k1])^4)/(14 (Norm[q])^2 (Norm[q - k1])^2)
```

Then fill in two symbols which represent vectors (and optionally use TraditionalForm):

```
f2s[q, k1] // TraditionalForm
```

which produces

[image]

You can then take the square and to review it apply [Expand](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Expand.html?q=Expand&lang=en) and TraditionalForm:

```
f2s[q, k1]^2 // Expand // TraditionalForm
```

which produces

[image]

Alternatively, if you wish to work with the components of the vectors (using numbers here as example)

```
q1 = {1, 2, 3}
q2 = {4, 5, 6}
```

write a function such as F2 (simplified here relative to the paper you mention)

```
f2[v1_, v2_] := (5/7) + (1/2) (v1.v2)/(Norm[v1] Norm[v2])
```

use it to evaluate for any two vectors

```
f2[q1, q2]
(* 5/7 + (8 Sqrt[2/11])/7 *)
```

then square it if you wish

```
f2[q1, q2]^2
```

If you want to work with generalized vector components and know the dimensions of each vector, use for example

```
q1 = {x1, y1, z1}
q2 = {x2, y2, z2}
f2[q1, q2]
```

Comment: I guess my question isn't well-framed. I didn't ask for such a thing. I am looking for an algebraic answer - and not for specific vectors you plugged in for $q1$ and $q2$. I can by hand calculate everything for general vectors - I guess there should be a way to do it in Mathematica also!

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood what you're looking for in terms of manipulation or calculation, or perhaps I don't know how to squeeze it out of Mathematica.

Comment: MMA symbolically transforms symbols. Vectors are represented as lists (and matrices as lists within lists) within a symbol. The 'simplest' form of a resulting expression is a matter of opinion, and FullSimplify makes particular choices when changing the form according to built-in Rules (which can be augmented by a user). Check out what MMA can do with [`SymbolicTensors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SymbolicTensors.html)?

Comment: You can see the edits that I made in the question. I guess now I have made my question more clear about what I want. It would be great if you can help!

Comment: Perhaps my edited answer is now closer to the mark. I have now applied the Expand command.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *Mathematica* version 9, the best approach is probably to use the new symbolic tensor functionality as suggested by zentient.

However for this problem it may be sufficient to explicitly specify a rule to convert expressions like `Norm[-q]` into `Norm[q]`:

```
myform = Expand[# /. Norm[-x_ + y_.] :> Norm[x - y]] &;

(F2s[q, k1]*F2s[-q, k2]) // myform // Short // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Thats quite sophisticated! So you are basically putting in an extra rule to convert Norm[-x+y] to Norm[x-y]. But how does Mathematica understand this to convert Nor[-q] to Norm[q]? Does it on its own put a $0$ vector for the blank slot of y?

Comment: @user6818, yes - the dot at the end of `y_.` tells *Mathematica* to use the default value for `Plus` (which is zero) if there isn't anything there to explicitly match the pattern. Look up `Default` in the documentation for a fuller explanation.

Comment: Great that there is a site like this! Its just impossible to know so many "tricks" with a software every time one has to do something - which is trivial to do by hand! So your "myform" specification also takes care of thinks like converting Norm[-x-y] to Norm[x+y] or Norm[x-y] to Norm[y-x] and all such possible combinations?

Comment: (..if it does all that a human would do with vector norms then I can go ahead use your script for various such large manipulations I would want to do - if the Norm factors are not combining well then I would have sieve through hundred of such expressions to pick by hand all the factors correctly!..)

Comment: @user6818, my code just converts expressions like `Norm[-a]` and `Norm[-a + b]` into `Norm[a]` and `Norm[a - b]`. You could add more rules if there are other transformations you need.

Comment: But conceptually its just one concept that the Norm of a negative of a vector is the same as the Norm of the vector. Can't this be made into just one rule to be specified?

Comment: More than that this is part of the definition of what is "Norm" of a vector. Why isn't this already known to Mathematica!? How else does one define Norm!?

Comment: Can this ":>" replacement trick be generalized to other cases as well? Like if I want to replace any occurrence of $2\vec{q}.\vec{k}$ by $\vert \vec{q} +\vec{k} \vert ^2 - q^2 - k^2$? (or to even start can I input a function with vector inner products? - algebraically and not with specific numbers and then do the above kind of replacement?)

Comment: Yes indeed. Symbolic pattern matching and replacement is the heart and soul of *Mathematica*. Remember though that `q` and `k` are just **symbols** - *Mathematica* doesn't know that you are using them to represent vectors. Hence why you will have to define specific transformation rules such as the one you suggest. Or take a look at the symbolic tensor stuff (it's not available in my version (8) so I don't know what the capabilities are)

Comment: No..it didn't work..you can see this question that I put up about this, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25696/doing-vector-manipulations-in-mathematica-part-2